# Can't activate wlan0 in CentOS5.5

Tags: wireless-networking, centos

When I try to activate wlan0 in CentOS5.5, I get this:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.

Determining IP information for wlan0...Internal network device wlan0 is not ready.
Aborting..
```

EDIT: I have the correct driver now, but it's still not working.

Comment: looks like a driver problem to me....or you have it active in some other mode so it can't set the mode...or you are trying to place it in a mode that isn't supported(monitor/promisc or AP).  need more information

Comment: All i know is that I'm trying to activate it in system-config-network

Comment: try using sudo...

Comment: sudo system-config-network

Comment: I did. That's how I accessed it.

Comment: the it's hosed driver/unsupported card or bad card

Comment: Great, how can I get a driver?

Answer (score 1):

Try `modprobe ath5k`, the drivers for your card should be in that module.
It has been part of the Linux kernel since 2.6.25 and Red Hat probably backported it to 2.6.18.

Comment: Done, but I get the same problem still

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, although coming from Fedora, from this article:
[Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) : SET failed on device wlan0](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=190053):

> The problem you are facing is that
>   there are two methods of controlling a
>   wireless card in Fedora. You are using
>   the one called "Network
>   Configuration". The preferred method
>   of controlling wireless cards is
>   "NetworkManager" which is a different
>   program.
>
> If NetworkManager is running, it
>   automatically stops Network
>   Configuration controlling your card
>   and you get the error you have found.
>
> If you have an entry for your card in
>   Network Configuration where you are
>   now on the "Devices" tab, highlight it
>   and click "Edit". In the new window
>   make sure that "Activate device when
>   computer starts" is NOT ticked. If it
>   is there then "Controlled by
>   NetworkManager" should be ticked. That
>   last will only be there if your Fedora
>   is relatively up to date.
>
> Then look for NetworkManager on the
>   top Gnome Panel in the notification
>   area to the right. When you left click
>   on it, it should present you with
>   available wireless networks. Left
>   click on one to be asked for any
>   encryption key and subsequently a
>   password to hide it behind.
>
> Should NetworkManager not be running,
>   go to the Gnome System Menu -
>   Adminsitration - Services, start it
>   and NetworkManager Dispatcher and save
>   the configuration.
>
> That got mine going.

Another possibility from [Set Failed on device wlan0](http://terrycoats.net/mywordpress/?p=450) :

> After bringing wlan0 down it accepted the command “sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc” and then I brought it backup again with “sudo ifconfig wlan0 up”. So, if you get this error message, try bringing the interface down first and see if that works.

---

Since your card is the AR5001, it is known for having problems under Linux.

The article [Atheros 802.11g PCMCIA card](http://linux.seindal.dk/2004/07/25/atheros-802-11g-pcmcia-card/) says :

> The Atheros chip-set is supported by the madwifi driver, which is not a part of the standard Linux kernel, but it can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/madwifi/.

This article then describes how to download and install the driver.

Another useful article might be : [Atheros AR5xxx devices (MadWifi)](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/ath_pci), althogh coming from Debian it might be less relevant.

For installation on CentOS, see this : [Setup MadWifi on Centos5](http://xiaobingyu.blogspot.com/2008/12/setup-madwifi-on-centos5.html).
If this doesn't work, maybe you can find a suitable release here : [Index of /madwifi](http://packages.sw.be/madwifi/) (found via google, have no idea who this website is).

Comment: Neither solution was much help, but thanks for trying

Comment: What is your card?

Comment: And does this help : http://lists.shmoo.com/pipermail/hostap/2003-July/003458.html

Comment: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Found some more stuff that seems useful for the AR5001.

Comment: Madwifi doesn't seem to want to make for me.

Comment: I have added above info specific for CentOS.

Comment: ar5001 has worked with ath5k for some time now...i use it for that particular chipset in my netbook.  it not being well supported on linux is a thing of the past.  since the transition to mac80211 it even supports AP mode.

Comment: @aking1012: For the OP's sake, I hope you are right. If he accepts the answer of kenny.r, then I will delete my answer. It just bothers me that MadWifi is still advocated for CentOS 5, and that the repository I found even contains an rpm for CentOS 6.

Comment: @harrymc I can get my head around why it would bother you.  I just already battled ath5k/madwifi back and forth on a couple of distros.  CentOS seems to me to be slower to adopt newer ways of doing things in favor of the tried and true madwifi.  On the plus side for madwifi - I seem to remember it exposing more options(transmission power etc) than the ath5k driver.  That's another possible reason for the recommendation.