# Archlinux/atheros WLAN configuration troubles

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm trying to config archlinux to use my wireless network adapter. It's quite troublesome. From what I've gathered, it's an atheros network adapter, using the ath5k driver/module...

I can't get it to work; any ideas? Here's some of the output from my tinkering:

```
# lspci | grep -i net
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: nVidia corporation MCP67 Ethernet (reva2)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: atheros communications inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev01)

# lsusb
...
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 03f0:17d Hewlett Packard Wireless (Bluetooth + WLAN Interface [Integrated Module]

# ping -c 3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com

#ping -c 3 8.8.8.8 
ping: network is unreachable

# lspci -v
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: atheros communications inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev01)
    ...
Kernel driver in use: ath5k
Kernel modules: ath5k

# dmesg |grep ath5k
registered as phy0
registered led device
ath5k: atheros chip found
PCI INT A disabled
registered led device
registered as phy1

# ip addr | sed '/^[0-9]/!d;s/: <.*$//'

1: lo
2: eth1
3: eth0

# ip link set <interface> up/down
RNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
```

Also, is there a way to dump text from command-line to a text file so i can just copy pasta? Sorry, first time using a linux distro...

EDIT: So I just tried this:

I actually just did this twice. (I can't tell which setting is on/off for my wireless adapter. The lights are blue all the time now.)

```
#rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: wireless lan
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :yes
1: hp-bluetooth: bluetooth
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :yes
3: phy1: wireless lan
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :yes
#rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: wireless lan
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :no
1: hp-bluetooth: bluetooth
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked no
3: phy1: wireless lan
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :yes
7: hci0: bluetooh
    0: hp-wifi: wireless lan
    softblocked: no
    hardblocked :no
```

I've dug around some [other](https://superuser.com/questions/210756/cant-activate-wlan0-in-centos5-5) [articles](http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/About/ath5k) and it seems like ath5k is supposed to be preferable to madwifi, so should i be using madwifi? I'm 99% sure I disabled the hardblock (by turning it ON) but, as shown above, phy1 wireless lan is STILL hardblocked. What gives? Maybe I've made some more fundamental error in a basic config file?

EDIT: I've fixed the hardblock. I've tried pinging www.google.com, but to no avail. I get:

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

In the arch wiki:

> Edit /etc/hosts and add the same HOSTNAME you entered in /etc/rc.conf: 
>   `127.0.0.1      archlinux.domain.org   localhost.localdomain      localhost    archlinux`

To my understanding, hostname is just a user-specified and based on preference(?)

My /etc/rc.conf:

> `HOSTNAME="gestalt"`

My /etc/hosts:

> `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost gestalt`

but should it be the following?

> `120.0.0.1 localhost.domain.org localhost.localdomain localhost gestalt`

Comment: How did you "fix the hardblock"? Does `rfkill list` now show the interface as *not* hardblocked *or* softblocked?

Answer (score 1):

`RFkill` is a Linux subsystem for turning on/off radio devices. "Operation not possible due to RF-kill" means RFkill was used to disable the wireless card.

Use `rfkill list` to check the wireless status:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

There are two levels of blocking – "soft block" is software-triggered (such as by clicking "Disable Wireless" in GNOME), while "hard block" is enabled using a hardware switch or a firmware setting.

If the list only shows your WLAN card being soft-blocked, use `rfkill unblock <number>`.

If the list shows a hard block, however, you cannot change it from within the OS – look for a "WiFi" keyboard button, an option in the BIOS/UEFI setup screen, or a physical on/off switch.

(Most laptops have Fn+*something* configured to turn off the wireless card, but it's not always the same – in some laptops it enables a hard-block, in others it's a soft-block.)

Comment: Edit: ok so I can't post code here?

Comment: *Posted results of rfkill list in OP. Does the fact that the WLAN+Bluetooth is integrated have something to do with my problem? o-o

Answer (score 0):

I have archlinux and i use the same module for my wireless card. You should remove the module. Using

> rmmod ath5k

And next press the button to turn on your wireless card, once did that insert the module again:

> modprobe ath5k

This always works fine for me.